# Error :invalid protocol while installing phonegap

Tags: sudo

```
pramod@pramod-Inspiron-5520:~$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
npm ERR! Error: Invalid protocol
npm ERR!     at Request.init (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:361:51)
npm ERR!     at new Request (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:124:8)
npm ERR!     at request (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:1279:11)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.makeRequest (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:208:13)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:117:17)
npm ERR!     at null._onTimeout (/usr/lib/nodejs/retry/lib/retry_operation.js:32:10)
npm ERR!     at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pramod
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pramod/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please put a question in the body? Reading output without any frame of reference as to what you are looking to accomplish, settings, what you were doing, etc. make it hard to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> npm ERR! Error: Invalid protocol

will show when the proxy is not set to a full absolute URL.

You need to do a ...

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

where username, password, host and port need to be changed to fit your situation.